# Toggle CheckBox Cell in DataGridView Programmatically

Tags: vb.net, winforms

When user unchecks the checkbox for the datagridview row, messagebox displayed, if the user answers yes the row is deleted, if the user answers no then I need to re-check the check box. however it doesn't actually check unless i click anywhere on the datagridview afterwards. Any ideas to get the dgv to updated?

```
Private Sub DataGridView2_CellValueChanged(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles DataGridView2.CellValueChanged

  If e.RowIndex <> -1 Then
    Dim row As DataGridViewRow = DataGridView2.Rows(e.RowIndex)
    If e.ColumnIndex = 0 Then
      If row.Cells(0).Value = False Then
        If MessageBox.Show("Delete view from database.", "Delete", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo) = DialogResult.Yes Then
          DataGridView2.Rows.RemoveAt(e.RowIndex)
        Else
          row.Cells(0).Value = True
          DataGridView2.Invalidate()
        End If
      End If
    End If
  End If
End Sub

Private Sub DataGridView2_CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles DataGridView2.CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged
  If DataGridView2.IsCurrentCellDirty Then
    DataGridView2.CommitEdit(DataGridViewDataErrorContexts.Commit)
  End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of `Invalidate()`, try calling `RefreshEdit()`, like this:

```
Else
  row.Cells(0).Value = True
  DataGridView2.RefreshEdit()
End If
```